# How to log request body before it is processed using CommonsRequestLoggingFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` is working fine when logging the incoming request bodies. However, it only logs them after the processing is done. So, when I log the response body, it precedes the request body. I would like to know if there's a way to log the request before it is even processed.

Another thing I would like to mention is that `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` actually is aware when the request is received, it logs message like `Request received at...`. However, that log doesn't contain the request body. After the message is processed, it logs almost exact thing with payload in it.

My configuration is the following for the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`. It has nothing special.

```java
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```

**Note**. Apparently there's a reason for the behavior mentioned above. It is said that `getContentAsByteArray` cannot be called until either `getInputStream` or `getReader` is called. This method is called inside the logger. I don't know what to do with this. Does it mean there's no way of logging request before?

Comment: I have a similar problem in past, CommonsRequestLoggingFilter does not provides any out of box option to log payload in before request as the request body is in InputStream which can be read only once. But I remember there are solutions where people have written there own filters in which they use ContentCachingRequestWrapper so that request body can be read twice.

Comment: Here are the few examples for reference:- http://www.programmergirl.com/spring-http-request-logging/ ,  https://github.com/yuhuachang/java-spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-rest-logging/src/main/java/com/example/restlogging/logging/HttpRequestResponseLoggingFilter.java

Comment: `ContentCachingRequestWrapper#getContentAsByteArray` method returns an empty array, if the InputStream or Reader has not already been called. I tried to write a similar thing but the content array was always empty.

Comment: @JaspreetJolly, thanks I used the example in Github link. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can log both before and after interceptor's execute() method like below.

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
      throws IOException {
    logRequest(request, body);
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    logResponse(response);
    return response;
  }

  private void logRequest(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("URI         : {}", request.getURI());
      log.debug("Method      : {}", request.getMethod());
      log.debug("Headers     : {}", request.getHeaders());
      log.debug("Request body: {}", new String(body, "UTF-8"));
    }
  }

  private void logResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("Status code  : {}", response.getStatusCode());
      log.debug("Status text  : {}", response.getStatusText());
      log.debug("Headers      : {}", response.getHeaders());
      log.debug("Response body: {}", StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I configure this? How can I "activate" this. Because I cannot add it as an Interceptor in Config class

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this an I've determined that it's probably not best practice to log the request/response bodies.

Starting with Spring Boot 2.0 it's not (and really hasn't officially been) supported.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12953#issuecomment-383830749

Comment: The other answer is an interceptor for a RestTemplate, not a Servlet interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

IDK how to trigger flushing of request stream. I had to read body after `filterChain.doFilter()`:

```
public class RequestResponseLogFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        } finally {
            // Log request after filter chain completed - so req body stream flushed and non-empty.
            logReq(requestWrapper);

            logRsp(responseWrapper);
        }
    }
}
```